# Continue and go back in the form

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, java-ee-5, jeet-grid

I develop a web application in java jee, and I would like to know how to use the button continue and go back in the post method in a form?
thank you in advance

Comment: you can use a form and then put your action where you want go like continue or go

Comment: I would use both actions to go back and forth in my form without using the backspace of the browser. Already I can continue specifying in form action. How to go back?

Comment: Yes suppose I return this way. If I want a button to continue in the same form I do how keeping this code back?

Comment: try below answer

Comment: It seems you need [`memento`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) pattern. If you need it in java.

Answer (score 0):

suppose your back page name is `back.jsp` then use

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/back.jsp" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="back"/>
</form>
```

suppose your forward page name is `forward.jsp` then use

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/forward.jsp" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="next"/>
</form>
```

Comment: It is not possible to manage these multiactions in the same form with different buttons?

Comment: you use a single form with two button

Comment: Excuse me for tiring you!
How to associate two actions back and continue in the same form. These actions are to move to the URL of the next page or the url of the previous page with the different buttons associated.